# Are questions on chords with more than one possible chord symbol not allowed?

Tags: discussion

So I asked a question regarding a chord which could possbily have more than one chord symbol. The answers to the question also said that there could be more than one chord symbol. But now my question is put on hold, as it is considered "off topic". Why is it so?

[What is the chord symbol for the marked chord? [on hold]](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84358/what-is-the-chord-symbol-for-the-marked-chord)

Comment: Hi Grace - it is worth reading through our extensive [about] and [ask] pages, as well as anything on here or the wider meta.stackexchange.com tagged faq. Loads of guidance there.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 6):

The closure banner on your question explains the reason it was closed:

> Questions about transcribing or finding a particular song, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers.

That is, "identify this one chord for me" questions are off-topic because they're not useful to anyone else. It makes no difference whether there might be one or several ways of writing the particular chord.

If you have a more generally applicable question about writing chord names - a question that's not specific to a particular piece but could help others as well - then that's more likely to be on-topic. For example, you could ask about what rules to follow to decide which name to use when transcribing a chord that has more than one name. Such a question would be useful to anyone transcribing any piece.

Comment: Alright, got it

Comment: Hi @grace - if an answer helps you, instead of commenting, please upvote it and click on the accept checkmark